# jwt tokens not working correctly after login (Advice needed on logic of code)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt

Hi I have been struggling significantly with making a login using react front end, npm express, npm mssql and npm jsonwebtokens.

I understand the logic behind this but cannot implement properly into my application. I have included the code in which I am getting stuck on and which is causing the issues.

This is my login route within my server.js (main npm packages used are mssql, express, jsonwebtokens,bodyparser)

This route is used when the logging form is submit (front end not important within this question).
This then checks if the database contains that email and password. If it does it prompts user "login successful" if not it prompts user "bad creds". If login is successful it assign a jwt token to it.

```
app.post("/login", async (req, response) => {
  try {
    await sql.connect(config);

    var request = new sql.Request();
    var Email = req.body.email;
    var Password = req.body.password;

    console.log({ Email, Password });

    request.input("Email", sql.VarChar, Email);
    request.input("Password", sql.VarChar, Password);

    var queryString =
      "SELECT * FROM TestLogin WHERE email = @Email AND password = @Password";

    //"SELECT * FROM RegisteredUsers WHERE email = @Email AND Password = HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @Password + 'skrrt')";

    const result = await request.query(queryString);

    if (result.recordsets[0].length > 0) {
      console.info("/login: login successful..");
      console.log(req.body);

      jwt.sign({ Email }, "secretkey", { expiresIn: "30m" }, (err, token) =>
        res.cookie("auth", token).json({ token })
      );
    } else {
      console.info("/login: bad creds");
      response.status(400).send("Incorrect email and/or Password!");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Err: ", err);
    response.status(500).send("Check api console.log for the error");
  }
});
// Verify Token
function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
  // Get auth header value
  const bearerHeader = req.headers["authorization"];
  // Check if bearer is undefined
  if (typeof bearerHeader !== "undefined") {
    // Split at the space
    const bearer = bearerHeader.split(" ");
    // Get token from array
    const bearerToken = bearer[1];

    // verify the token and store it
    jwt.verify(bearerToken, "secret", function(err, decodedToken) {
      if (err) {
        console.info("token did not work");
        return res.status(403).send("Error");
      }

      // Set the token
      req.token = bearerToken;
      req.decodedToken = decodedToken;

      next();
    });
  } else {
    // Forbidden
    res.sendStatus(403);
  }
}
```

I then have a token verify method.
This is supposed to check the token and then if it is legit will store it. However when using route user-questions(will show in next block of code) it always throws the 403 error.

```
// Verify Token
function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
  // Get auth header value
  const bearerHeader = req.headers["authorization"];
  // Check if bearer is undefined
  if (typeof bearerHeader !== "undefined") {
    // Split at the space
    const bearer = bearerHeader.split(" ");
    // Get token from array
    const bearerToken = bearer[1];

    // verify the token and store it
    jwt.verify(bearerToken, "secret", function(err, decodedToken) {
      if (err) {
        console.info("token did not work");
        return res.status(403).send("Error");
      }

      // Set the token
      req.token = bearerToken;
      req.decodedToken = decodedToken;

      next();
    });
  } else {
    // Forbidden
    res.sendStatus(403);
  }
}
```

This is the user question route in which on the first line I am trying to call the verify Token method when this fetch is called however it always throws the 403 error.

```
app.get("/user-questions", verifyToken, function(req, res) {
  // if a request has made it to this point, then we know they have a valid token
  // and that token is available through either req.token (encoded)
  // or req.decodedToken

  sql.connect(config, function(err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);

    // create Request object
    var request = new sql.Request();

    // query to the database and get the records
    request.execute("dbo.ViewQuestions", function(err, recordset) {
      if (err) console.log(err);

      // send records as a response

      res.json(recordset);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: At first glance it looks like the secret your using to sign your jwt and the secret your using to verify it are not the same. One is "secretkey" and one is "secret". These need to match, or `jwt.verify` will always return an error.

Comment: Hi I have updated now thanks for the advice. Unfortunately this has not changed the error I receive.

Comment: put a `console.log(bearerToken)`just before the `jwt.verify()`, and show us the output.

Comment: When you are testing this, and subsequently receiving the 403, how are you testing it? You're setting the JWT in a cookie, so I assume you're pulling this out in the react front-end and then making the call? In the `verifyToken` method, could you `console.log` the value of `bearerHeader` just after you assign it and post back the output, just as `jps` said above.

Comment: this does not actually appear within the console when I do that. Sorry for any gaps in knowledge this is my first day trying to implement these.

Comment: I am testing by logging in and then manually navigating through the url to user-questions routes and then looking at chrome dev tools to see what has happened usually just within the console within chrome dev tools.

Comment: Okay, what I suspect is happening is that when you log in, you set the JWT in the user's cookie. Therefore, in order for your `/user-questions` route to authenticate it is expecting to pull the JWT out of an authorization header, which by navigating to the URL directly, you don't have. For testing purposes right now (for the sake of this question), change `const bearerHeader = req.headers["authorization"];` to pull it out of the cookie instead and see if that works. If it does, then my theory is correct and you need to make sure you have the auth header set before testing it.

Comment: where would i put  **const bearerHeader = req.headers["authorization"]; **?

Comment: You'll still want to have that. What I was saying above was just to enable you to see if what I suspect is wrong is actually the case. Essentially, in order for your `user-questions` route to work as you intend, you need to have the JWT in an auth header when making that request. Currently, as you said, you're logging in then manually navigating to `/user-questions`, which doesn't work because it is trying to verify a JWT that isn't present. In your react front end, you'd pull the value of the JWT from the cookie, then store it in an auth header before making the API call to `/user-questions`.

Comment: For now, just comment out `const bearerHeader = req.headers["authorization"];` and change it to `const bearerHeader = req.cookies('auth')` and then try it again. Let me know if that works and I can write this up in an answer with more detail.

Comment: Thanks Matt! I have done that now but within console it is displaying server error 500

Comment: and the error in vs code terminal is "Server running on port 5000
[0] { Email: 'test@codestone.net', Password: '123456789' }
[0] correct details
[0] TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'bearerHeader' of 'req.cookies' as it is undefined."

Comment: My bad, I think it should have been `const bearerHeader = req.cookies['auth']`. Try that

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'auth' of undefined

Comment: that is the new error lol

Comment: Could you post the output of `console.log(JSON.stringify(req.cookies))`

Comment: in the verify function or within one of the otgher routes ?

Comment: In the verify one. I have started a chat with you so the comments don't get too long.

Comment: It is undefined i believe Within the console there is a [] drop down and underneath it says undefined. Then it says 403

Comment: Go here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206014/room-for-matt-kent-and-coderstew and we can talk further